Incorrect proof that every compact metric space is complete
I want to prove that any compact metric space is complete without the use of the Heinz-Borel theorem or the fact that any compact metric space is sequentially compact. My proof is as follows:
Let $K$ be a compact metrix space, and $(a_n)$ be a cauchy sequence in the space. Then, assume that $(a_n)$ does not converge to some $a \in K$. If thats the case, then no subsequence of $(a_n)$ converges to some $a \in K$. Thus, for any $x \in K$ the ball $B(x, \frac{\epsilon}{2})$ contains only finitely many points of $a_n$. This is an open cover, and we can then reduce it to a finite subcover using the points $\{x_1, \ldots, x_k\}$. Since each ball contains finitely many $a_n$, and there are a finite amount of balls, we must have a finite amount of $(a_n)$, which is impossible. Therefore, $K$ must be complete.
A second question relies on this proof, which I think is incorrect:
Let $K$ be a compact metrix space, and $(a_n)$ be a cauchy sequence in the space. Then, assume that $(a_n)$ does not converge to some $a \in K$. If thats the case, then no subsequence of $(a_n)$ converges to some $a \in K$. Thus, for any $x \in K$ the ball $B(x, \frac{\epsilon}{2})$ contains only finitely many points of $a_n$.
But not that $(a_n)$ is cauchy, and thus $\forall m, n > N(\epsilon)$:
$$
d(a_n, a_m) < \epsilon \iff a_n \in B(a_{N(\epsilon)}, \frac{\epsilon}{2}), \forall n > N(\epsilon)
$$
Thus, there exists some ball centered on $a_n \in K$ with infinitely many points. this is a contradiction, and thus $K$ must be complete.
My question is where does the second proof go wrong? I cannot make this any less vague, I don’t begin to know where it goes wrong, but it doesn’t rely on Ks compactness in any sense, which would imply every metric space is complete. The first one is correct (I think) and they start out the same way, so why does the second one fail?

There is a problem with both proofs: you mention a number $\varepsilon$ without saying anything about it.
In the case of the first proof, that is easy to repair: you can say that, for each $x\in K$, there is some $\varepsilon_x>0$ such that the open ball $B(x,\varepsilon_x)$ only has finitely many $a_n$'s. Since $K$ is compact, there are $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\in K$ such that $K=\bigcup_{k=1}^nB(x_k,\varepsilon_{x_k})$. But then there are only finitely many $a_n$'s. From here, together with the fact that $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence, it is easy to prove that $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is constant after some point, which is impossible, since then it would converge and it is being assumed that it does not.
But in the case of the second proof there is no way of repairing the fact that nothing is said about that number $\varepsilon$.

Thank you so much!
